# Clone Enity framework POCO

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, poco

I need to clone an Entity Framework object  into a new  object so i can save it into the database  .
Is there any easy way to do this without reflection    ?
If reflection is the only way to go then please post some code for me too   .

The question here 
[How to Clone POCO entity and add to context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934208/how-to-clone-poco-entity-and-add-to-context)
is using serialization and i do not see a need for doing that , also the answer is not using DbContext so its totally irrelevant to my question  .

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Clone POCO entity and add to context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934208/how-to-clone-poco-entity-and-add-to-context)

Comment: and you are too lazy to post a solution ?  or you dont know ?

Comment: I wish there was an automated AI system that removes trash comments .

Comment: I miss lmgtfy - lots of non-reflection options. I'll add automapper depending on your needs.

Comment: Sure: "SO: a place where you post your wishes and other people fulfill it". Actually, to educate you further and to our mutual benefit, I will use this opportunity to point you to this excelent explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: i think the guys who know the subject are posting relevant answers . Others are just spamming it  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice turn around .

If you try MemberwiseClone()  to get a copy of the object and then add the object to the context and SaveChanges()   you will get an error because the 
MemberwiseClone() does clone the Dynamic Proxy too .

So my turn around is

Create a new Context just for the cloning purposes  .
then do

ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Customer   copy =     ctxClone.Customers.Find( 2).Copy()

Copy here is the method you defined that  just calls   MemberwiseClone  underneath  .

then do

ctx.Customers.Add(copy);
ctx.SaveChanges() ;

This is the closest route i found to handle this problem .

If you prefer the reflection  solution then go for it .

Fyi   if you ProxyCreationEnabled = false in your other code you will loose change tracking and lazy loading  , so be careful about it .

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an extension method I wrote to populate the common values of two objects.

```
    public static void PopulateInto(
        this object source,
        object target,
        BindingFlags flags)
    {
        foreach (var pi in source.GetType().GetProperties(flags))
        {
            var tpi = target.GetProperty(pi.Name, flags);

            if (tpi.IsNotNull())
            {
                try
                {
                    object originalValue;
                    object value = originalValue = source.GetValue<object>(pi.Name, new object[0], flags);
                    try
                    {
                        value = Convert.ChangeType(originalValue, tpi.PropertyType);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                    tpi.SetValue(target, value, new object[0]);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Sharp Ninja for a nice contribution .